# Using a loop variable within ${ } in JavaScript to access element of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a java web application within which I have defined a class called 'Image'. Some attributes in this class are
source (base64 representation of the image)
width
height

At one point in my application I am using a servlet to pass an array consisting of objects of the 'Image' class to a jsp page by using the following statement.

```
request.setAttribute("images", imageDetails);
```

I have a script within this jsp page which needs to access this array. 
I can access the source attribute of a particular object of this array by specifying the index as follows.

```
var test='${images[0].source}';
```

However, my requirement is to access each Image object's source attribute. But replacing the array index with the loop variable 'count' as follows does not seem to work.

```
var count;
for (count=0;count<5;count++)
{
    var test='${images[count].source}';
}
```

Would appreciate if someone could show me how to use a loop variable to access attributes of each object.

Comment: You mentioned that it didn't work. Did it show you any errors? Or just simply doesn't show anything?

Comment: You cannot have a clientside loop over serverside data like that. `images[count]` is evaluated at the server, `count++` is done in the browser.

Comment: You seem to be mixing up *server-side* code and *client-side* code.  Your Java code runs on the server and creates an HTML/JavaScript page which is delivered to an ran on the client (the web browser).  When your `for` loop is ran by the browser, the Java code is long complete.  JavaScript has no idea what `images` is, because that's a Java variable.  You need to either run this loop on the *server* or save the *entire* `images` array as a JavaScript array and then loop over that.

Comment: @toy, it doesn't show anything. I used an alert(test); statement to see what will be displayed. When I used the index, the base64 string was displayed 5 times. But when I used the loop variable, nothing was displayed.

Comment: [Expresion interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Expression_interpolation) in javascript requires the backtick character ` not quote '

Comment: @emed: I didn't know JavaScript had a `${}` syntax.

Comment: @emed, var test=`${images[count].source}`; also does not work

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat, I was under the impression that when 'images' is set as an attribute by the servlet and the response is sent to the client, a copy of the entire 'images' array is sent to the client. So the JavaScript code would access the 'image' array passed to the client. Isn't this the case?

Comment: @Nilushan: I don't actually know, sorry.  I don't use Java.

Answer (score 1):

You have written your loop inside  tags which will cause them to behave in an unexpected manner because your loop is disturbed by loading of JSP page. 
So that you have to add

```
<body onload="functionName()">
```

and within that function, you can have your loop

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find a way to access the passed objects the way I wanted to as described in my question.
However I was able to solve my problem which led to it by using JSON.

I first converted my array of Image object to JSON using the Gson library and then passed it from the servlet as follows.

```
Gson gson=new Gson();
String imageDetailsJson=gson.toJson(imageDetails);
request.setAttribute("imageDetailsJson", imageDetailsJson);
```

Then I accessed it from a JavaScript script within my jsp page, parsed it using the JSON.parse() function and then looped through it.

```
var temp = '${imageDetailsJson}';
var json = JSON.parse(temp);
for (count = 0; count <5; count++)
{
    test = json[count]["source"];
}
```

By doing so, I was able to access the 'source' attribute of each image object.